# JQ Create multi level json

Tags: json, jq

I am looking to create a JSON file from scratch that looks like this:

```
{
   "Key1": {
      "SubKey1": "Value1",
      "SubKey2": "Value2"
    }
}
```

I have the following variables in my bash script:

```
$key1
$subkey1
$subkey2
$value1
$value2
```

I have tried a couple of JQ without results:

```
   jq --arg key1 $key1 \
  --arg subkey1 $subkey1 \
  --arg value1 $value1 \
  --arg subkey2 $subkey2 \
  --arg value2 $value2 \
  '[$key1].[$subkey1]=$value1 | [$key1].[$subkey2]=$value2' <<<'{}'
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting FORMAT or QQSTRING_START (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.[key1].[subkey1]=$value1 | .[key1].[subkey2]=$value2        
jq: 1 compile error

    jq --arg key1 $key1 \
   --arg subkey1 $subkey1 \
   --arg value1 $value1 \
   --arg subkey2 $subkey2 \
   --arg value2 $value2 \
   '.$key1 | .[$subkey1]=$value1 | .[$subkey2]=$value2' <<<'{}'
{
  "SubKey1": "Value1",
  "SubKey2": "Value2"
}
```

But I don't get the correct results.

Comment: fyi, this works:
```
jq --arg key1 $key1 --arg subkey1 $subkey1 --arg value1 $value1 --arg subkey2 $subkey2 --arg value2 $value2  '.Key1.SubKey1=$value1 | .Key1.SubKey2=$value2' <<<'{}'
```
but I need Key1 and SubKey1 & SubKey2 as variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach using multiple --arg flags can be made to work as illustrated below:

```
key1=Key1
subkey1=SubKey1
subkey2=SubKey2
value1=Value1
value2=Value1

jq -n --arg key1 "$key1" --arg subkey1 "$subkey1" --arg subkey2 "$subkey2" --arg value1 "$value1" --arg value2 "$value2" '
{
   ($key1): {
       ($subkey1): $value1,
       ($subkey2): $value2
    }
}
'
```

### Alternatively ...

```
.[$key1] = (.[$subkey1]=$value1 | .[$subkey2]=$value2)
```

Comment: so when I try to append another subkey to key1, it gets a little weird: jq --arg key1 $key1   --arg subkey1 $subkey3   --arg value1 $value3    '.[$key1] = (.[$subkey1]=$value1)' out.json
{
  "Key1": {
    "Key1": {
      "SubKey1": "Value1",
      "SubKey2": "Value2"
    },
    "SubKey3": "Value3"
  }
}

Comment: got it! jq --arg key1 $key1 \
  --arg subkey1 $subkey3 \
  --arg value1 $value3 \
'.[$key1] = (.[$key1] | .[$subkey1]=$value1)' out.json